# Do I need a new table for a new language?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, localization

Do I need to create a different table for each new language?

Here's a sample table:

```
field
id   
field
lang 
filter
count
```

Say someone inputs data in English, then they input data in Japanese, then they input data in Russian....  Is that going to be acceptable?  Or rather, is there a good way to make it possible because I get the following error, making me believe that I should re-design:

```
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE8\x8B\xB1\xE8\xAA\x9E' for column 'field' at row 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Unicode to allow all languages within your database. Clients should also process and transfer captured data in Unicode.

Comment: Would you say this is an effective way to localize, or should I use some kind of translation table(s) set up?

Comment: Usage of Unicode is the most effective and most common way to set allow different languages to be used with your application. But, of course, if A inserted data in Chinese, B will also see Chinese signs ;)

Comment: Also, when browsing, I get `e88bb1e8aa9e` rather than `英語`.

Comment: Anyway, Unicode was _created_ to solve the problem you described.

Comment: As I mentioned above, you should make all your client applications, all your server-side scripting etc. to process data in Unicode. If you have issues with your browser, try to set encoding manually within the page you are looking at.

Comment: Well, granted that it's effective as far as linguistic capacity, I'm wondering about functionality.  Some basic automated translation would be possible with a set of translation tables, I guess.  On the other hand, there's never universality in translation.  So, that functionality could come from elsewhere.

Comment: Oh.  okay.  I'll try that, suddnely. :)

Comment: Plus also I don't know exactly what you should do when you change encoding of your database in mySQL. For example, MSSQL converts all the data in tables automatically.

Comment: Well, I'm using PHPMyAdmin.  It shows `e88bb1e8aa9e` where it should show the Japanese characters for `eigo`, which just means 'English'.  I changed my browser's default encoding to UTF-8, and I set a compatible font, Ms Mincho.  Still the numbers, though.  I'm thinking it's something to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Okay, I got it.  I was using `UTF-8_bin_ci` and not `UTF-8_unicode_ci`, so I got binary when viewing rather than unicode.  Also, I really like your answer.  Thank you.